# Rename Vim buffer, but not the content

Tags: vim, buffer

Can you rename a vim buffer while not renaming the associated content ?

In this particular scenario, I'm running a conqueterm and want the buffer name to be the log file name that I've associated with the buffer, not the buffer name produced by conque term.  More typically, this would be to rename the buffer without renaming the associated file.

Answer (score 6):

In general, no. Changing the buffer name changes the name that a file will be written to.

But for buffers that do NOT correspond to files, you can rename the buffer as you see fit. The `:file` command lets you do this. See `:help :file_f`. However, some plugins may depend on the buffer name of their special buffer to locate that buffer. So you might end up breaking the plugin if you rename the plugin's special buffers willy-nilly.

Comment: Thanks - searching on the obvious strings in vim help does not yield this answer.  Yes, the conqueterm buffer did rename via :file, but as you anticipated conqueterm did not behave well in commands that go back and forth between the conqueterm buffer and other buffers.  Looks like the solution is to update the conqueterm code that specs a buffer name.  Preferable to that would be an enhancement at the vim-level.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just want a custom, window-local `'statusline'` setting. This (in its default value) includes the buffer name, but by changing the value for those windows, it'll appear with a more natural name, yet still persist (with `:w` etc.) to its original.